# self "not a structure or a union" in a UIViewController class. Why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, properties

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out what the problem is... but with no success.

My code is the following:

```
ResultGoalViewController *resultGoalViewController = [[ResultGoalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultGoalViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.goalNavigationController pushViewController:resultGoalViewController animated:YES];
```

I get the error:
"error:Request for member 'goalNavigationController' in something not a structure or a union."

My class is UIViewController.
goalNavigationController is a Navigation Controller (defined within a Tab Controller).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

`goalNavigationController` should be a property or an accessor in your `UIViewController` subclass.

Comment: Don't forget your semicolons!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like `self` doesn't have a `goalNavigationController` property. If it does, you should post where it's declared so we can see that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chuck, thanks Mipadi.

I have a goalNavigationController property in the delegate application.

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;
UITabBarController *mytabBarController;
NavigationGoalViewController *goalNavigationController;
```

}

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NavigationGoalViewController *goalNavigationController;

@end
```

But it's not in my current UIViewController Class, as my goalNavigationController was first built/called within my delegate application. I am now calling it from the ViewController of the first view of my Navigation (I am trying to load the second view of my navigation controller).